# Why do most home automation products only control incandescent light bulbs?

Tags: home-automation

I have a new bare apartment due soon to work with. It's my first time investigating home automation but all I come up with are home automation products for incandescent lighting. Yet all my rooms have main fluorescent lights. Do I just have bad luck and somehow googled only incandescent light home automation? Or is this how the current home automation industry is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that a part of many home automation controls are built in dimmer switches to control the level of lighting.  You can't use a dimmer control with florescent light fixtures.  The alternative is to use an appliance control instead.  An appliance control is on/off only, and this will work with flourescent light fixtures.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what products you have been looking at, but I've had good luck with SmartHome's [Insteon](http://www.smarthome.com/_/INSTEON/_/23b/land.aspx) product line.  For non-dimmable florescent lights, you want the *relay* switches.  They allow you to turn lights on and off, but not dim them.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into those but the electricity here is 220v/50hz, I don't think Insteon supports 220/50 yet. So far I've only found X10 and Zwave which do. The home automation project is for a 200 square meter apt. For now, I'm leaning towards the X10 which should be adequate for the purpose of the budget conscious newcomer hobbyist.